# "Device herring not found on server" when installing Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am getting this message when trying to get my Nexus S eat Ubuntu:

```
jason@jason-Asus:~$ sudo ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
2014/05/25 22:43:30 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2014/05/25 22:43:30 Device is |herring|
2014/05/25 22:43:30 Device herring not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com channel devel
```

anybody some idea?

Answer (score 3):

Nexus S is not an officially supported phone, see [Ubuntu Touch Devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices). There are some test images released by a third party, but they have been discontinued and are unsupported.

Comment: Note that most of non-supported devices will show this message.